# When is "var" parsed?

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript, adobe-javascript

Sometimes `var` affects code before it, and sometimes not. Take this example:

base.jsx:

```js
$.global.a = 1;
$.writeln("a: " + a);
var a = 2;
```

Running this prints `a: 1`. Running `$.evalFile("base.jsx");` also prints `a: 1`. However, running

```js
(function() {
    $.evalFile("base.jsx");
})();
```

prints `a: undefined`.

Why? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Javascript has a lot of quirks, which I believe are mostly "historical", not some well designed thought (just what happened to be done by some first implementation). Don't try to find logical reasons for every misfeature of Javascript...

Comment: @Basile My goal is to be able to predict the result of my code before running it. Is there a rule that ExtendScript is following here, or is it just a huge collection of quirks and edge-cases that cannot be adequately defined by a set of rules?

Comment: Then, adopt some coding rules, including declaring by `var` your variables at the beginning of the function containing it...

Comment: I find the "parsing" adjective quite confusing and wrong. The `var` keyword is surely parsed (because parsing is left to right). What matters is the scoping of the declared variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bunch of testing, I figured it out.

I knew that JavaScript's scopes are function-level, but I had assumed that files also have their own scope. I was wrong.

Running

```js
$.global.a = 1;
var a = 2;
$.writeln("$.global.a: " + $.global.a);
```

will print `$.global.a: 2`. This means that `$.global.a` and `var a` are exactly the same thing in this context, and the scope of the file is actually the global scope.

Given that base.jsx is still

```js
$.global.a = 1;
$.writeln("a: " + a);
var a = 2;
```

Running the code

```js
(function() {
    $.evalFile("base.jsx");
    $.writeln("a: " + a);
    $.writeln("$.global.a: " + $.global.a);
})();
```

changes the scope of base.jsx to be this function instead of the global object. Suddenly `$.global.a` and `var a` are referring to two different objects. The result of this will be:

```
a: undefined
a: 2
$.global.a: 1
```

So the problem was never that `var` is sometimes parsed early and sometimes not. The problem is that files have no scope other than the global one.